# Blazored Modals do not seem to open

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, blazor, blazored

I've followed this guide: https://github.com/Blazored/Modal. (Currently I have installed latest stable Package - 5.0.2).
I went through these steps:

1. Installed the Package
2. Added imports
3. Changed the CascadingBlazoredModal
4. Added both the references in _host
5. Changed Index.razor to the following code:

```
@page "/"
@inject IModalService Modal

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to Blazored Modal.

<button @onclick="@(() => Modal.Show<FetchData>("Fetched data"))" class="btn btn-primary">Fetched data</button>
```

I've tried several different solutions (including: switching browser, using only bootstrap) - nothing seems to work.

I have noticed an odd thing - none of the other buttons seem to work (they are clickable, but no action is done), so that may be a clue to solving this bug.

I would be also glad if someone could help me out with a simple div that looks like a Modal popup as that would make things much easier.

Comment: Did you check browser logs and console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap modal depends on java script manipulating css classes and styles directly on the element.
I quickly knocked this up to show how Blazer can be used to manipulate the same classes it is not complete.

Modal.razor

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  @onclick="ToggleModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="@modalClass" tabindex="-1" style="display: @displayMode;" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
       <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h5 class="modal-title" >Modal title</h5>
                <button class="close" @onclick="ToggleModal" aria-label="Close" >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @ChildContent
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary"  @onclick="ToggleModal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@code {

    bool open = false;
    string modalClass => open ? "modal fade show" : "modal fade";
    string displayMode => open ? "block" : "none";


    private void ToggleModal()
    {
        open = !open;       
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to fix this you need to add the following code to the MainLayout.razor

```
<CascadingBlazoredModal />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).